# Efficient but yet readable way to type an object whose properties are all the same type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

The code takes a set of numbers and builds the version as major.minor.patch.build
So the return object for the function is this:

```
export interface versioning { 
  major:number,
  minor:number,
  patch:number,
  build:number
}
```

I just got a bit worried about repeating number several times.

Is there a better way to re write this?

Comment: That's as short as you can go. There is no problem in repeating `number`, as it's just a data type. In this case you happen to have several variables with the same type, and that's fine. It would have been a problem if you need to repeat the same code over and over.

Comment: Don't worry, it's just four properties, and the equivalent `export interface Versioning extends Record<"major" | "minor" | "patch" | "build", number> {}` is uglier and more confusing.  (But do name your types conventionally with UpperPascalCase, so `Versioning` and not `versioning`.)  Note that as asked this seems like an opinion question; instead of asking for a "better" way, can you rephrase to a form for which an objective answer is possible?  (If you really just want code review, there's a [better place](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?tags=typescript) for that)

Comment: @jcalz yes but codereview normally kick me out if it's not a full program they can test...I will rephrase. Thanks for the peaceful comments.